# Spring Integration - pass data from 2 tables into one processor class

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration along with Spring JPA.

I need to pass information from 2 tables into a processor class. Is there any way to do it?

System diagram + Code below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is not clear. You just do a join between those tables and get some POJO based on the data returned by the `SELECT`. Sounds like you need to consult with JPA basics:

```
select s from B b, A s where b.bPK.id_A=s.id_A and b.PK.id_C= :idEvent
```

or

```
select s from A s join s.b b where b.PK.id_C= :idEvent
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Query_Results

I'm not sure that the task can be achieved with the Spring Data JPA repositories.
Custom queries - welcome: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Thankyou @ArtemBilan. I did not want to create a new POJO to store the result from the join.

Say, table-A and table-B were the 2 DB tables.
class-A and class-B were the corresponding Entity classes.
I want to read data from table-A, store it into object of class-A, read data from table-B, store it into object of class-B.
I want to pass the object of class-A and object of class-B into the processor class.
Is there anyway of doing this?
Sorry, I am new to Spring JPA and do not know much about it.

Comment: Do, maybe you don't need Spring Data JPA at all then and you can just rely on the plain `EntityManager` to perform JPAQL as we discussed above?